# Client.db is not defined (MongoDB backend API) error

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express

I'm trying to get data from a collection in my MongoDB backend and keep running into an error that my client is not defined. I was wondering if anyone has encountered this, and what needs to be added to make this work?

Error:
Client is not defined.
const db = client.db('products');

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const user = require("./routes/user");
const cors = require('cors');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongo_uri = 'mongodb+srv://***:***@cluster0.fetfl.gcp.mongodb.net/*****?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const db = client.db('products')
const collection = db.collection('brand')

MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(client => {
    console.log('connected');
    const db = client.db('products');
    const collection = db.collection('brand');
    app.listen(port, () => console.info(`REST API running on port ${port}`));
}).catch(error => console.error(error));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('brand').find().toArray().then(results => {
            console.log(results)
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do not have `client` defined. What you do have defined is `MongoClient`.
So probably, the code that you are looking for is:

```
const db = MongoClient.db('products')
```

The client objects itself is not defined.

Comment: When I added MongoClient, I get the same error - except with Mongo added to it.

Comment: Did you change it at both the places? You seem to be using it in two places.

Comment: I have - it's telling me it's not a function.

Comment: It worked when I deleted the const declaration in the top of the server.js file. I've also changed .then(client => {... to .then(MongoClient => {...